# 3ds Max C# plugin Class_ID possibly not instantiated

Tags: c#, 3dsmax

I get the following error when starting 3ds Max to test the plugin I am writing:
"A software problem has caused 3ds Max to close unexpectedly."
The prompt and the view report details window show no additional information as to where the error occurred exactly.

I read the C++ tutorial and am following the Autodesk tutorial 3ds Max SDK Programmer's Guide and Reference, the Writing .NET Plug-ins part.

How can I get further information on where the error occurred exactly?

Before adding constructors, an instantiation error occurred in the descriptor class:

```
public class Descriptor : Autodesk.Max.Plugins.ClassDesc2
{
    IGlobal global;

    public IGlobal Global
    {
        get { return this.global; }
    }

    public Descriptor(IGlobal global)
    {
        this.global = global;
    }

    public override IClass_ID ClassID
    {
        get { return this.Global.Class_ID.Create((uint)0x28ca31e0, (uint)0x622d62c8); }
    }
    public override bool IsPublic
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    public override string Category
    {
        get { return InternalName; }
    }
    public override string ClassName
    {
        get { return "Utilities"; }
    }
    public override SClass_ID SuperClassID
    {
        get { return SClass_ID.Utility; }
    }

    public override object Create(bool loading)
    {
        return new Utilities(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: No one here is going to download your project, no one is paid to do this, we are volunteers and help because we like to add to the knowledge of the site and like reoccurring up-votes on good questions and answers.. Ask your self, next week when your link disappears what value does this question become to the community?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I hope the edits I made are in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Descriptor.Create() should be called from the descriptor:

```
    public Descriptor(IGlobal global)
    {
        this.global = global;
        Create(true);
    }
```